# How can I add the values of the same keys in different dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have something like this:

```
A = {"Green":{"Small": 5, "Medium": 10, "Large": 15}, "Yellow": {"Small": 7, "Medium": 14, "Large": 21}}

B = {"Green":{"Small": 1, "Medium": 2, "Large": 3}, "Yellow": {"Small": 3, "Medium": 6, "Large": 9}}
```

I want to write a function to get a dictionary "C" like this:

```
C = {"Green":{"Small": 6, "Medium": 12, "Large": 18}, "Yellow": {"Small": 10, "Medium": 20, "Large": 30}}
```

Which is just the sum of each value for it's key (which is the same in all dictionaries. Right now my "solution" is way too long and certainly not elegant. Can anyone give me some pointers on how I can make a relatively short function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function which takes an arbitrary number of dictionaries in the form OP describes:

```
from pprint import pprint

def dsum(*args):
    return {
        k1: {
            k: sum(d.get(k1, dict()).get(k, 0) for d in args)
            for k in set.union(*(set(d.get(k1, dict())) for d in args))
        }
        for k1 in set.union(*(set(d) for d in args))
    }

A = {"Green":{"Small": 5, "Medium": 10, "Large": 15}, "Yellow": {"Small": 7, "Medium": 14, "Large": 21}}

B = {"Green":{"Small": 1, "Medium": 2, "Large": 3}, "Yellow": {"Small": 3, "Medium": 6, "Large": 9}}

C = {"Green":{"Small": 6, "Medium": 12, "Large": 18}, "Yellow": {"Small": 10, "Medium": 20, "Large": 30}}

testC = dsum(A, B)
assert C == testC
pprint(testC)
```

Comment: You might want to understand the Big-O performance of my code before pointing it at large data sets.

Comment: I have been trying to understand the code, though I am having a difficult time with it. It will only be used for small data sets, so complexity shouldn't be a problem for this particular case. I will experiment with it a bit until I understand it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good old loops:

```
C = {}
for k, v in A.items():
    inner = {}
    for inner_k, inner_v in v.items():
        inner[inner_k] = inner_v + B[k][inner_k]
    C[k] = inner

>>> C
{'Green': {'Large': 18, 'Medium': 12, 'Small': 6},
 'Yellow': {'Large': 30, 'Medium': 20, 'Small': 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C={k: {kk: v + B[k][kk] for kk, v in a.items()} for k, a in A.items()}
```

prefer `.iteritems()` in python2

Answer (score 0):

A solution for missing keys:

```
def merge_by_addition(d1, d2):
    def m2(d1_, d2_):
        keys_ = set(d1_.keys()) | set(d2_.keys())
        return {k_: (d1_.get(k_, 0) + d2_.get(k_, 0)) for k_ in keys_}
    keys = set(d1.keys()) | set(d2.keys())
    return {k: m2(d1.get(k, {}), d2.get(k, {})) for k in keys}
```